# php iconv character encoding from Thai ISO-8859-11 to utf-8

Tags: php, unicode, iconv

I am trying to convert this string "¤Á¢Ó(ªéÓ) ¹ÒÂ·Í§ãº" from iso-8859-11 to utf-8. And I use this code for it:

```
iconv('ISO-8859-11', "UTF-8", "¤Á¢Ó(ªéÓ) ¹ÒÂ·Í§ãº")
```

But it returns false. I have tried another solution which was encoding each character separately by this code:

```
function forceUTF8($charset, $string) {
$convertString = '';
$badChars = [];
$stringLength = mb_strlen($string);

$convertString = iconv($charset, "UTF-8", $string);

if ($convertString === false) {       
    for($i = 0; $i < $stringLength; $i++) {
        $char = mb_substr($string, $i, 1);
        $convertChar = iconv('ISO-8859-11', "UTF-8", $char);

        if ($convertChar === false) {
            $badChars[$i] = $char;
        } else {
            $convertString .= $convertChar;
        }   
    }
}

return $convertString;
```

}

and it returns this:
ยคยข(ยชรฉ) ยนยทยงรฃยบ

which is incorrect and should be like this:
คมขำ(ช้ำ) นายทองใบ

I noticed that this "ย" character is repeating after every one or two characters:
**ย**ค**ย**ข(**ย**ชรฉ) **ย**น**ย**ท**ย**งรฃ**ย**บ

I could find the reason behind this. But I don't know why this happens. The reason is when it goes for this character "¤", it returns its UTF8 hex code which is ["c2 a4"](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=1024). the character should be A4 in ISO-8859-11 charset that is **ค** but instead, it will go and find c2 first in [ISO-8859-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-11) which is this character "ย", and then adds a4 to it.

What is the reason behind this? And what should I do?

Comment: `"¤Á¢Ó(ªéÓ) ¹ÒÂ·Í§ãº".encode('cp1252').decode('cp874')` in Python returns desired string `'คมขำ(ช้ำ) นายทองใบ'`. Sorry, I can't  show corresponding `php`/`iconv` code…

Comment: Thank you... But can you please explain why you first encode it to cp1252?

Comment:  because [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) is my *compulsory* hobby since early 1980's . Unfortunately, nothing changed even with up-and-coming Unicode (nor UTF-8 invention later)…