# php iconv character encoding from Thai ISO-IR-166 to utf-8 doesn't work

Tags: php, encoding, character, iconv, thai

Why this line of code:

```
$convertedChar = iconv('ISO-IR-166', "UTF-8", '¤');
```

returns "ยค" instead of "ค"?

also

```
$convertedChar = iconv('ISO-IR-166', "UTF-8", 'Á');
```

returns false instead of "ม".

Comment: Probably because `¤` is _not_ encoded in `ISO-IR-166` to begin with. What character encoding did you save the script file containing this code in?

Comment: It saves as a UTF-8

Comment: So specifying `ISO-IR-166` as input charset would simply be a lie then … This feels like a constructed test scenario (and a badly constructed one, at that.) Can you explain what _actual_ problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Even utf8_decode('¤') returns "Â¤"

Comment: Yes, I defined it completely here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130456/php-iconv-character-encoding-from-thai-iso-8859-11-to-utf-8?noredirect=1#comment120470080_68130456

Comment: I get the string from the database which its saved character encoding is "ISO_IR 166" and I want to convert it to UTF-8

Comment: You can not reproduce that with an example like above, because the `¤` _is not_ in ISO-IR-166 encoding, if you saved your script file as UTF-8. And if it does not work with content read from the database - then that is likely not in ISO-IR-166 either. (_Stored in_ the database, is not necessarily the same as what you _read from_ the database. The character encoding of the connection might come into play here as well.)

Comment: In regard to your example from the other question, where `¤` is _supposed to be_ `A4` - once you actually provide that character byte value as input, it works fine: https://3v4l.org/AIuMe

Comment: This platform uses UTF-8. You cannot simply display other codings in a reproducible manner here.
This requires a special function that uses the hexadecimal representation. Use plaese this function to show your input. //Returns a string with escaped chars in hexadecimal notation
function strToHex2($str) {
   return '\x'.rtrim (chunk_split(strtoupper(bin2hex($str)), 2,'\x'),'\x'); 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all your helps I've got to this result:

```
$convertedChar = iconv('ISO-IR-166', "UTF-8", utf8_decode('¤'));
```